# How can I make time look similar to my system clock?

Tags: javascript, macos, time

I want to create output that matche my computer ( macOS ) as close as possible.

My computer's time looks like this:

[image]

I don't need the AM or PM.

I just need hour:minute:second

I looked at [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and [now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) but did not see an obvious solution.

What is the most straightforward and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
const clock = document.querySelector('where you want to output the time');

function setDate() {
const now = new Date();
const seconds = now.getSeconds();
const minutes = now.getMinutes();
const hours = now.getHours();
clock.innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

**new Date()** Allows you to get the current time

**getSeconds(), getMinutes(), getHours()** Allows you to get the seconds, minutes and hours out of the date you put before. Here the date is **now** and you refresh the clock every second via **setInterval(setDate, 1000)** so you basically refresh & display the current time every second with that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time with [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and then you can call [.getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours), [.getMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes), and [.getSeconds()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getSeconds) on that object to get the hour, minute, and second components.

Comment: The original version of this answer recommended using `.getUTCHours()`, which gets the current hour _in the UTC time zone_.